# Adding variants in Mac Ports

Tags: macos, macports

I was wondering how you can append a variant to a port if you have already installed the port. For example I installed the 'vim' port and would like to go back and add the python25 variant. Do I need to delete vim and reinstall it? This is just an example, I would really like to know the process to do this for any port.

Thanks for any help,
Greg

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Only one variant of a `MacPorts` port can be active at any one time.  However, in `MacPorts` terminology,  multiple variants and/or versions of a port can be `installed` simultaneously.  Of those, at most one is `active`, any others are `inactive`.  If you need to occasionally alternate between variants, you can *activate* a specific variant as needed.  That will also automatically deactivate any conflicting active port.  For example, here's a hypothetical `vim` example (not fully tested!):

```
$ sudo port install vim +python26
$ sudo port clean vim
$ sudo port install vim +python31
$ sudo port echo installed |grep vim
vim                            @7.3.21_0+python26
vim                            @7.3.21_0+python31
$ sudo port activate vim @7.3.21_0+python26
# ... edit with Python 2
# ...
$ sudo port activate vim @7.3.21_0+python31
# ... edit with Python 3
# ...
```

Comment: I'm confused. Since a variant is a compile time option vim +python26 builds vim with python26 support. You are then recompiling it with python31 support. How does it keep both compile options? Is this a Mac Port feature?

Comment: I'm not an expert on the internals but essentially it keeps copies of each `installed` port (look in `/opt/local/var/macports/software/`). The process of activating a port creates hard links from the files in there to the normal locations (`/opt/local/bin` etc).  Deactivating a port removes those hard links.  So the process is fast and does not require extra copies of each file, just the hard link entries.

Answer (score 9):

I believe macports supports this natively now with the `--enforce-variants` option. So in the above case, the command would be

```
$ sudo port upgrade --enforce-variants vim +python25
```

Answer (score -2):

You do need to reinstall. There's no way to add a variant on afterwards – nor does it even make sense to do so. Variants affect settings during the build process.

Comment: this is incorrect, I have done many re-`install`s which add a variant.

Comment: Exactly, you reinstalled. Which is what I said.

Comment: Sorry what you said is right. I suppose it’s confusing because the question is “do I need to DELETE a port and then reinstall it?”, to which the answer is “No”, you just run the Install command again with the new variant included. Indeed this is “reinstalling”.

Comment: That's a fair criticism. Though if you do reinstall, you probably should delete the old one so you're not wasting disk space, but you can just clean those up later with `port uninstall inactive`.